# @Value: Exception at Spring Injection of autowired dependencies with application-'profile'.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven

The application has 3 different application.properties files

```
application.properties
application-aws.properties
application-local.properties
```

on the default:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

on the other 2

```
amazon.access.key=accesskey
amazon.access.secret-key=secretkey
amazon.region=local
amazon.end-point.url=localhost:8000
```

In the config class:

```java
@Configuration
public Class AmazonConfig(){

    @Value("${amazon.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.access.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${amazon.end-point.url}")
    private String awsDynamoDbEndPoint;
...
}
```

In the `pom.xml`

```xml
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

...

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.active>local</spring.profile.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>aws</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.active>aws</spring.profile.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Trying to build the application with `mvn spring-boot:run -P aws/local`
I'm getting the following error on the atributes annotated wit `@Value`

`INFO: The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@`

`WARN: IllegalArgumentException - Injection of autowired dependencies failed - Could not resolve placeholder 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"`

In some links here they said include a space after *$*, like this:

```java
@Value("${amazon.access.key}")
```

to this:

```java
@Value("$ {amazon.access.key}")
```

My intention is to be able to run the 'local' configurations so it will
address to my local container with

`mvn spring-boot:run -P local`

and when I want to test the AWS configuration

`mvn spring-boot:run -P aws`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a maven plugin:

```xml
<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</builds>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your default application.properties I think you want the following:

`spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@`

Comment: I tried replacing and rebuilding, but still getting the same error.